# Parallel For Loop

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to utilize the parallel for loop in .NET Framework 4.0. However I noticed that, I am missing some elements in the result set.

I have snippet of code as below. **lhs.ListData** is a list of nullable double and **rhs.ListData** is a list of nullable double.

```
int recordCount = lhs.ListData.Count > rhs.ListData.Count ? rhs.ListData.Count : lhs.ListData.Count;

List<double?> listResult = new List<double?>(recordCount);
var rangePartitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, recordCount);  

Parallel.ForEach(rangePartitioner, range =>
                    {
                        for (int index = range.Item1; index < range.Item2; index++)
                        {
                            double? result = lhs.ListData[index] * rhs.ListData[index];
                            listResult.Add(result);
                        }
                    });
```

**lhs.ListData** has the length of 7964 and **rhs.ListData** has the length of 7962. When I perform the "*****" operation, listResult has only 7867 as output. There are null elements in the both input list.

I am not sure what is happening during the execution. Is there any reason why I am seeing less elements in the result set? Please advice...

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use LINQ's `IEnumerable.AsParallel()` extention.  It does all of the partitioning for you, and everything in PLINQ is inherently thread-safe.  There is another LINQ extension called `Zip` that zips together two collections into one, based on a function that you give it.  However, this isn't exactly what you need as it only goes to the length of the shorter of the two lists, not the longer.  It would probably be easies to do this, but first expand the shorter of the two lists to the length of the longer one by padding it with `null` at the end of the list.

```
IEnumerable<double?> lhs, rhs;    // Assume these are filled with your numbers.
double?[] result = System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip(lhs, rhs, (a, b) => a * b).AsParallel().ToArray();
```

Here's the MSDN page on `Zip`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply. And it works fine for me. I always need to output the shorter list. How would I change the logic above for division where I need to check if b == 0?

Comment: The part that is `(a, b) => a * b` is just a regular lambda, and you could replace it with anything that is a `Func<double?, double?, double?>`, including a method inside your class.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the operations on a `List<T>` (e.g. `Add`) are not thread safe - your results may vary. As a workaround you could use a lock, but that would very much reduce performance.

It looks like you just want each item in the result list to be the product of the items at the corresponding index in the two input lists, how about this instead using PLINQ:

```
var listResult = lhs.AsParallel()
                    .Zip(rhs.AsParallel(), (a,b) => a*b)
                    .ToList();
```

Not sure why you chose parallelism here, I would benchmark if this is even necessary - is this truly the bottleneck in your application?

Comment: This hypothesis is confirmed by the `List<T>` page on MSDN.  It states that `List<T>` is thread-safe for reading concurrently, but not for writing.  Locking the list is the suggestion that it provides too.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `List<double?>` to store results but `Add` method is not thread safe.
You can use explicit index to store the result (instead of calling `Add`):

```
listResult[index] = result;
```